¿Como darle animación a un timeline por desplazamiento?
Estoy diseñando una sección de timeline ya tiene animación solo que cuando recargo la página hace su efecto, lo que quiero es que cuando llegue al punto o al desplazarse comience la animación.


 
  .texto1 {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: rgb(134, 5, 151);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   }

   .texto2 p, .texto3 p{
    background-color: rgb(58, 7, 243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }


.eventos{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #976a83;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.eventos h2{
  font-family: "Courgette", cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #fff3cd;
  font-size: 25px;
}


.timeline{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.text-box{
  background: #edbfd9;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #080808;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.contenedor{
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
 animation: movedown 1s linear forwards;
 opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes movedown{
0%{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
100%{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
}

.contenedor:nth-child(1){
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(6){
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(7){
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.contenedor:nth-child(8){
  animation-delay: 7s;
}


.right-contenedor{
  left: 72px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.contenedor img{
  position: absolute;
  background: #edbfd9;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -45px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.right-contenedor img{
  left: -46px;
}

.timeline::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #edbfd9;
  top: 0;
  left: 52px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  animation: moviline 6s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes moviline{
  0%{
    height: 0;
  }
  100%{
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.text-box h2{
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #080808;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.right-contenedor-arrow{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #edbfd9;
  left: -9px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollinabiltar.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body> 
     <section id="seccion3">
      <div class="container">
      
        <dvi class="texto3" id="texto3">
          <h1>Seguimiento de lectura</h1>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>

        </dvi>
    
      </div>
      <div  class="eventos">
        <h2>Aplicaciones y Hardware</h2>
        <div class="timeline">
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=12370&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Mememoria ram</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=vaQUFtPEp5nj&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>HHD</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
         <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=uLWV5A9vXIPu&format=png&color=000000">
          <div class="text-box">
            <h2>Facebook</h2>
            <small>Aplicación</small>
            <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=16713&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>whatsApp</h2>
              <small>Aplicación</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=13349&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Memoria USB</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=Xy10Jcu1L2Su&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Instagram</h2>
              <small>Aplicación</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
       </div>

      
   </section>
  

   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>




Lo que quieres son animaciones dirigidas por scroll (scroll driven animations en inglés).
Para mostrar las imágenes conforme se vaya llegando a ellas, puedes usar algo sencillo:
view-timeline: --muestra-imagen y;
animation-timeline: --muestra-imagen;
animation-range: entry 25%;

Añade eso a la clase .contenedor (y puedes borrar los animation-delay de después.) Con view-timeline se asocia un nombre (cualquier nombre variable que quieras) y dirección (en este caso en el eje y) al timeline, luego asocias ese timeline a la animación con animation-timeline. Y finalmente con animation-range indicas cuándo debe dispararse la animación (en este caso, cuando se haya sobrepasado un 25% el inicio del elemento, puedes poner 0% si prefieres o el valor que quieras.)
Luego recomendaría añadir algo parecido a la animación que muestra la línea vertical (y, más para que se vea mejor en la demo, he hecho que cada elemento empiece con un opacity de 0 en vez de 1).
Con estos cambios, ya puedes hacer scroll dentro de la página y las animaciones sólo se ejecutarán cuando el elemento entre en la vista y no cuando la página se cargue.
Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

Nota, estas propiedades de CSS son experimentales y pueden no funcionar en todos los navegadores.



.texto1 {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: rgb(134, 5, 151);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   }

   .texto2 p, .texto3 p{
    background-color: rgb(58, 7, 243);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
   }


.eventos{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #976a83;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.eventos h2{
  font-family: "Courgette", cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #fff3cd;
  font-size: 25px;
}


.timeline{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.text-box{
  background: #edbfd9;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #080808;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.contenedor{
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  animation: movedown 1s linear forwards;
  view-timeline: --muestra-imagen y;
  animation-timeline: --muestra-imagen;
  animation-range: entry 10%;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes movedown{
0%{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
100%{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
}


.right-contenedor{
  left: 72px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.contenedor img{
  position: absolute;
  background: #edbfd9;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -45px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.right-contenedor img{
  left: -46px;
}

.timeline::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #edbfd9;
  top: 0;
  left: 52px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  animation: moviline 6s linear forwards;
  view-timeline: --muestra-linea y;
  animation-timeline: --muestra-linea;
  animation-range: entry 0%;
}

@keyframes moviline{
  0%{
    height: 0;
  }
  100%{
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.text-box h2{
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: "Alegreya", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #080808;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.right-contenedor-arrow{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #edbfd9;
  left: -9px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilo.css" />
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollinabiltar.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body> 
     <section id="seccion3">
      <div class="container">
      
        <dvi class="texto3" id="texto3">
          <h1>Seguimiento de lectura</h1>
          <p>Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

            Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
            ¿Por qué lo usamos?
            
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
            Qué es Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
¿Por qué lo usamos?

Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).

        </p>

        </dvi>
    
      </div>
      <div  class="eventos">
        <h2>Aplicaciones y Hardware</h2>
        <div class="timeline">
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=12370&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Mememoria ram</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=vaQUFtPEp5nj&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>HHD</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
         <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=uLWV5A9vXIPu&format=png&color=000000">
          <div class="text-box">
            <h2>Facebook</h2>
            <small>Aplicación</small>
            <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=16713&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>whatsApp</h2>
              <small>Aplicación</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=13349&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Memoria USB</h2>
              <small>Hardware</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor right-contenedor">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=100&id=Xy10Jcu1L2Su&format=png&color=000000">
            <div class="text-box">
              <h2>Instagram</h2>
              <small>Aplicación</small>
              <span class="right-contenedor-arrow"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
       </div>

      
   </section>
  

   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>




No me funciona amigo al hacer scroll no realiza la animación.

Se me olvidó poner que ahora mismo solo Chrome soporta este tipo de animaciones.
